# Facebook not correctly pulling "og:image"

Tags: facebook

Starting about a week ago, Facebook no longer correctly pulls my "og:image" unless I use the Facebook debug tool and click on "scape again" several times.

I receive the following error message :

The provided 'og:image' properties are not yet available because new images are processed asynchronously. To ensure shares of new URLs include an image, specify the dimensions using 'og:image:width' and 'og:image:height' tags.

My code has been working perfectly for over a year and I have made no modifications to it.

Here is my code :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/example.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="220" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="220" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<Article Title>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<Article Desc>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<Article URL>" />
<meta property="og:see_also" content="<Article Alt URL>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="example.com" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
```

I've removed the real meta content, but I assure you all the meta tags are filled out correctly.

After hitting the "scape again" button a couple times, Facebook is finally able to pull the image.

There is 0.00 server load on my dedicated server so that's not the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It just suddenly stopped and I'm getting the same error despite providing height and width values. I think facebook have broken their own scraping system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was a Facebook issue, as everything magically started to work again without me making any changes.